# Find values from one excel sheet in another

Tags: excel

I have a column with the values in A excel sheet  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4.... and i have in B excel sheet another column with values 1 2 4 ...., what i want is read values from B and see if they are in A sheet, for example if value 2 is in B sheet, then write true in a new column in sheet A in front of 2, and similarly false or nothing in front of value 3.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple `VLOOKUP` - For example, assuming that the content of cell A1 of sheet B is 2, and that the sheet you call A is called `SheetA`, you can put the following formula in cell B1:

```
 =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,SheetA!A:A,1,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A1,SheetA!A:A,1,FALSE))
```

Comment: This approach would require the user's `VLOOKUP()` target be sorted, as that's a requirement for `VLOOKUP`.  Based on info the poster provided, his data are already sorted.  But it's an important caveat to note just in case they're not.

Comment: No, when using the `FALSE` option it does not matter if the list is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the approach described here:
http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/comparing_two_lists_with_conditional_formatting/

Key formula is this: `=COUNTIF(OldList,D2)=0`, which you can use within the conditional formatting context as described, or to generate your true/false indicators as you mention in your question, i.e.:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(OldList,D2)=0,FALSE,TRUE)
```

`OldList` is just a range, and you don't need to use a *named* range.  But if you don't name the range, just be sure to use absolute references for the range you're searching against.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a cool formula you can use to count the number of each matching value.  Try this for your original post:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A1 =Sheet1!$A:$A) > 0), "True", "False")
```

And this to count the values: 
`=SUMPRODUCT(--($A1 =Sheet1!$A:$A))`